# VBA Web scraping GetElementById - Select 1 Option drop down menu

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementbyid

**Issue Description:**
I have a complex VBA code for web scraping - using it to open Web Page, update fields by using **GetElementById** and then click "Save" button on specific page to create a new record.

There is only one Element, where I need to select with VBA 1 of 7 options called "Full R" from the list menu, but after I inspected Element on web page I'm not sure how to achieve it, as there are no Options available in Inspected Element (see screenshot below).

Here is the Element Inspected:

[image]

My Element id is "TakeoverCorporateActionType" and on web page I can choose from 7 different options when I click on dropbox menu

[image]

My goal is always to select same option "Full R" from 7 Options, but i'm not entirely sure how to do it.

There is a full private_sub I'm running as part of more complex code (believe this will enough to understand

```
Private Sub UpdateFXDATA(client As String, url As String, postNow As Boolean, finalRate As Boolean)

Dim editUrl As String, caUrl As String

Dim element As Variant

editUrl = "MY URL" 'hidden from security reasons

caUrl = "My URL 2" 'hidden from security reasons

lastRow = ws.Range("E12389").End(xlUp).Row

Set ie = GrabIE(ie, url)


Do While ie Is Nothing

    Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))

    MsgBox "please login to " & url & " in Internet Explorer."

Loop

For Each c In ws.Range("K3:K" & lastRow)

    Application.Goto c

    If c.Offset(0, 3).Value <> "Data Not Found" Then

    On Error GoTo 0

    Else

    ie.Navigate url & editUrl

 
    waitIE ie

    Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))


    ie.Document.getelementbyid("TakeoverCorporateActionType").Value = "Full Redemption"

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("ExDate").Value = c.Offset(0, -4).Value

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("ExDatecutoff1").Value = c.Offset(0, -4).Value

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("RecordDate").Value = c.Offset(0, -4).Value

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("ActionRequiredDate").Value = c.Offset(0, -4).Value

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("InstrumentCode").Value = c.Value

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("UnitOfOldStock").Value = 1

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("NewShares").Value = 0

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("ExternalEventIdentifierGenericOption1").Value = c.Offset(0, -2).Value

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("Compulsory").Value = 1

    If c.Offset(0, 2).Value = "" Then

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("CashAmount").Value = 0.001

   
    Else

    ie.Document.getelementbyid("CashAmount").Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value

       
        End If

    End If


        Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now))

      
        ie.Navigate ("javascript:btnSave_Click();")

       
        Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))  'added additional time to prevent fail

           
    Next c
```

The Part of the code focused on my problem relates to this line:

```
ie.Document.getelementbyid("TakeoverCorporateActionType").Value = "Full Redemption"
```

Comment: It would help to expand the options in your screenshot so we can see both the value and text for each option.  Click the arrow next to the select to expand it

Comment: What is the `value` property of the `option` tag in the `select` that you want to use?  That's what you set the `select` value to.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `ie.Document.querySelector("#TakeoverCorporateActionType > option[value='Full R']").Selected =True`

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. Issue was on my side, when I inspect Element, there were no options visible in the code, while when I opened whole view-source I could see them and saw that option names have different names, that's why my code couldn't work.

So this code works fine:

```
ie.Document.getelementbyid("TakeoverCorporateActionType").Value = "FullRedemption"
```